# VBScipt object inside Procedure

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make a clicking bot but I can't figure out why he doesn't work. Run Sub works but other doesn't. Can zou help me and explain how you pass object into a procedure? Much, much, much, much, thanks.

```
    Sub run()
    set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    wshshell.run "chrome.exe"
    wscript.sleep (5000)
    WshShell.Sendkeys "https://scrap.tf/raffles"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub

Sub find()
    wscript.sleep (5000)
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub

Sub enter()
    wscript.sleep (5000)
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub

Sub back()
    wscript.sleep (5000)
    WshShell.Sendkeys "%{LEFT}"
    wscript.sleep (5000)
End Sub

Call run
Call find
Call enter
Call back
```

Comment: You have to call your other subs from within another sub.  The vbscript is simply running your first listed sub.  It ignores the `Call` statements.

Comment: @jbarker2160, I don't agree - both the code in script global scope and using `call` statement works fine with VBS.

Comment: @omegastripes, then you have a better answer as to why it didn't work `in this specific case`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the object that should bу used in all your subs to the variable within global scope:

```
Set WshShell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")

Call run
Call find
Call enter
Call back

Sub run()
    WshShell.Run "chrome.exe"
    WScript.Sleep (5000)
    WshShell.Sendkeys "https://scrap.tf/raffles"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub

Sub find()
    WScript.Sleep (5000)
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub

Sub enter()
    WScript.Sleep (5000)
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub

Sub back()
    WScript.Sleep (5000)
    WshShell.Sendkeys "%{LEFT}"
    WScript.Sleep (5000)
End Sub
```